# How to enable SMB1 as default and disable SMB2 and SMB3 on Ubuntu 18.04 Server?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-ce, smb

I want to share files between Ubuntu 18.04 Server and Windows CE. I need to use only SMB1 protocol to connect to Windows CE because this system only supports SMB1. I tried to configure Samba  `/etc/samba/smb.conf` through:

```
[global]
protocol = SMB1

min protocol = SMB1
max protocol = SMB1

client min protocol = SMB1
client max protocol = SMB1
```

but nothing works.

Windows CE cannot connect to the shared folder.
I tried with Windows 10 and surprisingly it worked, but probably because I ran SMB1 support on Windows 10.

I'm aware of the danger of using outdated SMB1 protocol. But I have no other idea.
Is it at all possible to connect these two systems via SMB1?

Comment: Wich versione of wince are you using?
I'm aware that starting fron WinCE5 there is support for SMB V0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms898959(v=msdn.10)

Answer (score 7):

put in the [global] section of /etc/samba/smb.conf the directive

```
min protocol = NT1
```

samba calls SMB1 as NT1.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 (connecting a Ricoh Aficio MP 301 with a firmware previous to WannaCry problem https://www.ricoh.com/products/mfp20170727_1 )